# Can you calculate how long it would take to drain a battery given the watts?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

I'm looking at an LED light and it says it takes 2.2 watts with a 3.7V / 900 mAh battery.  How do I calculate how long the LED light will last if it's on continuously?

The item in question [is this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072QL568M)

Comment: Given that information, you can't. You also need to know the voltage. Then it's easy.

Comment: I might be wrong but considering your LED is 3.3v: 0,9Ah * 3.3V = 2,97W of power you've available, meaning your it will last 1,32h because the LED will take 2.2W every hour.

Comment: @TCB13 I'm being pedantic here but a watt is power and power is instantaneous so you can't "take 2.2W every hour".  The battery stores energy not power so you can take 2.2W continuously for an hour \$ (2.2\text{ watt} \cdot \text{hour}) \$ or you can express this energy in Joules.

Comment: @TCB13 Yes, you're wrong. You're multiplying the forward voltage of the LED by the battery capacity (in Ah. It's a charge, not a current!), this does not mean anything. 

You need also the battery voltage, to know how much energy the battery has (battery capacity * battery voltage). When you have that energy, you divide it by the LED's consumption. That's the best time you can hope for, assuming a 100% efficiency of the DC/DC convertery you'll probably must insert between the battery and the light.

Comment: @next-hack "You need also the battery voltage" yes I do, but I was considering 3.3v just to make it fast, not extremely correct.

Comment: @TCB13 it's not "not extremely correct". It's plain wrong.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I hope you're happy with the accepted answer. Still going on the overestimation route, because we never knew the DC/DC conversion eff. And also my comment was basically the same exact thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your battery voltage is V, its capacity (in Ah) is Q, and your lamp's power is P, and if you're using a DC/DC converter with efficiency: $$\eta$$

Then, the time is simply: $$\eta\frac{QV}{P}$$

Of course, to get the numerical result in hours, Q must be in Ah and P in W, and V in Volts.

This is a simplification, as it assumes a constant battery voltage V, until the battery is fully depleted.

Comment: This is the item https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072QL568M 3.7V

Comment: then looking at the specs put $$\eta=1$$ and V = 3.7.

Comment: I get 1.513... Is that supposed to be in hours?

Comment: @Jack Yes. Still I guess it could be an overestimation.

Answer (score 1):

**Considerations: Your LED runs at 3.3v.**

- mAh how much energy you have on your battery;
- Know how much you'll be using every hour;
- Consider that an amperage is a coulomb per second;

*The Math: Calculate how long the battery will last by dividing its total charge in mAh by your LED load in mA.*

**900 mAh / 666mA = 1,36h**
(I've considered your LED is 3.3V meaning 2,2/3,3 = 666mA).

If you're unsure about my math, you can also use this online calculator that will give your the same result: http://ncalculators.com/electrical/battery-life-calculator.htm

Comment: This assumes, that there is a linear regulator and not a switching converter, otherwise the answer is unknown without the battery voltage.

Comment: This is the item https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072QL568M 3.7V